# Static resource DataTemplate vs. inline DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate

1. Lets say I got a `CellContentTemplate` (of a column in a `DataGrid`), and I define its `DataTemplate` inline:

   ```
   <Column.CellContentTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>

       </DataTemplate> 
   </Column.CellContentTemplate>
   ```

Is there a difference in terms of memory usage in comparison to referencing by `StaticResource` to pre-defined `DataTemplate`?
After all the content of the `DataTemplate`is copied either way.

2. Let's say this `DataTemplate` has `TextBlock` with `Foreground` of "Green" in it. Does this "Green" brush is reused from row to row if I reference to `DataTemplate` by `StaticResource` or is it copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataTemplate` itself will only be created once regardless of whether you create it as a reuasable resource or inline. So there is no difference in terms of memory usage unless you create another instance of the `DataGrid`. Then there will be another instance of the inline `DataTemplate` created.

> Let's say this `DataTemplate` has `TextBlock` with `Foreground` of "Green" in it. Does this "Green" brush is reused from row to row if I reference to `DataTemplate` by `StaticResource` or is it copied?

The string "Green" that you defined in your XAML markup is resolved to `Brushes.Green` which is a static property of the `Brushes` class that returns the same cached and frozen brush each time.

Comment: And let's say instead of this green I have an inline LinearGradientBrush as the Foreground of this textblock. I guess now there will be a difference.

Comment: Then there will be an instance of the LinearGradientBrush created for each TextBlock.

Comment: And in case I got virtualization, the amount of those brushes will be as the amount of the items that appear...

Comment: Yes, you will get one TextBlock instance per visible cell more or less.